# topological groups in quotien mapping

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

**Theorem:**
suppose that $G$ is a topological group, $H$ is a locally compact subgroup of $G$, and $‎P‎$ ‎is a‎ ‎closed ‎symmetric ‎subset ‎of‎ $‎G$ ‎such ‎that‎ $‎P‎$ ‎contains ‎an ‎open ‎neighborhood ‎of ‎the ‎neutral ‎element‎ $‎e$ ‎in‎ $‎G$, ‎and ‎that‎ ‎$‎\overline{P‎^{3}‎ }‎ ‎\cap ‎H‎‎$ ‎is ‎compact. ‎Let‎ ‎$ ‎\pi :‎ G‎ ‎‎\longrightarrow G‎ /‎ H‎ ‎‎ $ ‎be ‎the‎ natural quotient mapping of $G$ onto the quotient $G/‎H$. ‎then the restriction of $‎f‎$  ‎of‎   $‎\pi$ ‎to‎  $‎P‎$ ‎is a‎ ‎perfect ‎mapping ‎of‎  $‎P‎$ ‎onto ‎the ‎subspace‎ ‎$ ‎\pi( P‎ ‎)‎ $ ‎of‎ ‎$ G /H $‎.‎

**proof:**

‎clearly ‎‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎continuous .‎ ‎first ‎we ‎show ‎that ‎$ ‎f‎^{-1}‎f ‎(a)‎ $‎‎is ‎compact, ‎for ‎any ‎$ a \in P $‎‎‎‎ ‎indeed ‎from ‎the ‎definition ‎of ‎$ ‎f‎ $‎‎we ‎have ‎$  ‎f‎^{-1}‎f ‎(‎a) =‎ ‎aH‎ ‎\cap ‎P‎ $‎  .‎ ‎the ‎subspace‎$ ‎aH‎ ‎\cap ‎P‎ $‎ ‎and ‎$ H‎ ‎\cap ‎a‎^{-1}‎‎‎P ‎$‎ ‎ ‎are ‎obviously ‎homeomorphic ‎and ‎closed ‎in‎$ ‎G‎ $‎ .  ‎since‎$ ‎a‎^{-1} ‎\in ‎P‎^{-1} ‎=P‎ $‎ ,‎ ‎ we ‎have‎$ H‎ ‎\cap ‎a‎^{-1}‎P‎ ‎‎‎\subset H ‎‎‎‎\cap  ‎P‎^{2}‎‎ ‎\subset ‎\overline{‎P‎^{3}‎} ‎‎‎\cap ‎H‎‎‎$‎ .‎ ‎hence  ‎$H‎ ‎\cap ‎a‎^{-1}‎P‎  $‎‎is ‎compact ‎and ‎so ‎is ‎the ‎set ‎$ ‎f‎^{-1}‎f ‎(a) ‎$‎.‎‎

‎close‎d:‎
‎let‎ ‎‎us fix any subset ‎$ ‎M‎ $ ‎of ‎$ ‎P‎ $‎ , and let‎$ ‎a‎ $‎ be a ‎point ‎of ‎$ ‎P‎ $‎ ‎so ‎that‎$ ‎f(a) ‎\in‎ ‎\overline{f(M)}‎ $‎ .‎ ‎we ‎show ‎$ f(a) ‎\in‎ f(M)‎ $‎.‎ ‎assume ‎the ‎country. ‎then ‎$ ‎(a‎H ‎\cap‎ ‎\overline{P‎^{2}‎}‎ ) ‎\cap M‎ =‎ ‎‎\emptyset‎‎ $‎.‎ ‎note ‎that  ‎$a‎H ‎\cap‎ ‎\overline{P‎^{2}‎}‎‎‎  $‎‎is ‎compact, ‎since ‎$a‎H ‎\cap‎ ‎\overline{P‎^{2}‎}  ‎$‎ ‎is ‎homeomorphism ‎to$‎‎H ‎\cap ‎a‎^{-1} ‎‎‎\overline{P‎^{2}‎}  ‎$‎ ,‎ ‎which ‎is a‎ ‎closed ‎subset ‎of ‎the ‎compact ‎space $‎‎H ‎\cap ‎‎‎ ‎‎‎\overline{P‎^{‎3‎}‎}  ‎$‎  ‎.‎‎

since‎  ‎$a‎H ‎\cap‎ ‎\overline{P‎^{2}‎}  ‎$‎ ‎is ‎compact ‎and ‎$ ‎M‎ $ ‎‎‎is ‎closed ‎and ‎disjoint ‎from ‎‎‎ ‎$a‎H ‎\cap‎ ‎\overline{P‎^{2}‎}  ‎$‎‎‎‎,‎ ‎there ‎exists ‎an  ‎open‎,‎symmetric‎  ‎neighborhood ‎$ ‎W‎ $‎ ‎of‎$  ‎e‎$‎ ‎in  ‎$ ‎G‎ $‎‎so that ‎$ (‎ ‎W( a‎H ‎\cap‎ ‎\overline{P‎^{2}‎}‎‎) ‎ ‎\cap M = ‎‎\emptyset ‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎ ‎and‎$ W‎ ‎‎\subset ‎P‎ $‎ ‎.‎

since ‎the‎  ‎‎quotient ‎mapping ‎$ ‎\pi‎ $ ‎‎is ‎open ‎and  ‎$ ‎Wa‎ $ ‎‎is  ‎open‎‎‎  ‎neighborhood  ‎of ‎$ ‎a‎ $‎ ,‎ ‎the ‎set‎$ ‎\pi (‎ ‎Wa)‎ $‎ ‎is ‎an‎ ‎open‎‎‎  ‎neighbourhood  ‎of$ ‎\pi ‎(‎a) ‎$‎ ‎in ‎$ G‎ /‎ ‎H‎ $‎ .‎‎ ‎therfore, ‎the ‎set‎$  ‎\pi (‎ ‎Wa)‎ ‎\cap‎  ‎\pi (‎M‎)‎   $‎ ‎is ‎not ‎empty, ‎and ‎we ‎can ‎fix ‎$ m‎ ‎\in ‎M‎ $‎‎ ‎and‎  ‎$ y‎ ‎in ‎W‎ $‎‎so ‎that ‎$ ‎\pi(m ‎)=‎ ‎\pi(ya)‎ $‎ ,‎ ‎that ‎is ‎$ ‎mH =‎ ‎yaH ‎$‎ .‎ ‎then ‎$ m‎ ‎=yah‎ $‎,‎ ‎for ‎some ‎$ h‎ ‎\in H‎ ‎‎ $‎ .‎ ‎however, ‎$  ‎ah = y‎^{-1}m \in ‎‎\overline{‎P‎^{‎2‎}‎}‎$‎,‎‎ ‎since  ‎$ y‎^{-1‎} ‎\in ‎W‎‎^{-1‎}  ‎=W ‎\subset P‎‎‎$‎‎and ‎$ M‎ ‎‎\subset ‎P‎ $‎ .‎ ‎beside ‎$ ‎ah ‎\in ‎aH‎ $‎.‎ ‎hence,‎$ ‎ah ‎\in ‎(aH‎ ‎\cap‎ {‎P‎^{‎2‎}‎}‎‎‎$‎  ‎and  ‎$ m‎ =‎ ‎yah ‎\in W‎ (‎ ‎aH ‎ ‎\cap‎‎ \overline{‎P‎^{‎2‎}‎})‎ $‎‎,since ‎$ y‎ ‎\in ‎W‎ $‎.‎ ‎thus ‎$ m‎ \in M‎ ‎‎\cap‎‎ (‎ ‎aH ‎ ‎\cap‎‎ \overline{‎P‎^{‎2‎}‎}) ‎$‎‎,‎ ‎which ‎contradicts ‎the ‎choice ‎of‎$ ‎W‎ $‎ .‎ ‎hence‎$ ‎f(a )‎ ‎\in ‎f(M)‎ $‎ ,‎ ‎and ‎‎$‎f(M) ‎‎$‎is ‎closed ‎in‎$ ‎(P)‎ $‎ ‎.‎
‎

> my questions are:

1:To show that a perfect mapping,  must show that the mapping is closed and continuous mapping?
why$  is ‎f‎^{-1}‎f ‎(‎a) =‎ ‎aH‎ ‎\cap ‎P‎ $?(in the first part)

2:why is $ ‎(a‎H ‎\cap‎ ‎\overline{P‎^{2}‎}‎) ‎\cap M‎ =‎ ‎‎\emptyset‎‎ $‎?( in second part)

3:why is $ (‎ ‎W( a‎H ‎\cap‎ ‎\overline{P‎^{2}‎}‎‎) ‎ ‎\cap M = ‎‎\emptyset ‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎? ( in third part)

4:why‎ ‎‎is ‎not the ‎set‎$  ‎\pi (‎ ‎Wa)‎ ‎\cap‎  ‎\pi (‎M‎)‎   $‎  ‎empty?( in forth part)

> thanks for your pay attention.  ‎

Answer (score 1):

**Ad 1.** It follows from this simple lemma (which I leave as an exercise):

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function and $A\subseteq X$. Define $g:A\to Y$, $g(x)=f(x)$ (i.e. the restriction). Then for any $B\subseteq Y$ we have $g^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}(B)\cap A$.

**Ad 2.** He assumes that $f(a)\not\in f(M)$. This means that $aH\cap M=\emptyset$ because otherwise if $m\in aH\cap M$ then $f(a)=f(m)$ (because $m\in aH$) and thus $f(a)\in f(M)$.

**Ad 3.** Let's make it into a lemma:

> Let $G$ be a topological group, $C\subseteq G$ compact, $M\subseteq G$ closed and $C\cap M=\emptyset$. Then there exists an open, symmetric neighbourhood $U$ of $e\in G$ such that $UC\cap M=\emptyset$.

*Proof.* Put $V:=G-M$ (the complement of $M$). Obviously $V$ is an open neighbourhood of $C$ such that $V\cap M=\emptyset$.

Now consider the multiplication $\circ:G\times G\to G$. Since $\circ$ is continous then $\circ^{-1}(V)$ is open in $G\times G$. By the definition of product topology for any $c\in C$ there are open subsets $U_c, W_c\subseteq G$ such that $W_c\times U_c\subseteq \circ^{-1}(V)$, $e\in W_c$ and $c\in U_c$ (we just take open neighbourhoods around $(e, c)$). By compactness of $C$ we have a finite set of indexes $c_1,\ldots, c_m$ such that $\{U_{c_1},\ldots,U_{c_m}\}$ covers $C$. Put $$W:=W_{c_1}\cap\cdots\cap W_{c_m}$$
$$U:=U_{c_1}\cup\cdots\cup U_{c_m}$$
 It follows that $C\subseteq U$ and $WU\subseteq V$. Since $V\cap M=\emptyset$ then $WC\cap M=\emptyset$.

All in all $W$ is open and contains $e\in W$ and $WC\cap M=\emptyset$. To make $W$ symmetric simply refine it: $W':=W\cap W^{-1}$. Obviously $W'$ is open, $e\in W'$, $W'$ is symmetric and $W'\subseteq W$. Thus $W'C\cap M=\emptyset$. $\Box$

**Ad 4.** Since $f(a)\in\overline{f(M)}$ then by the definition any open neighbourhood $U$ of $f(a)$ has to intersect nonempty with $f(M)$. Note that $M\subseteq P$ so $f(M)=\pi(M)$ and obviously $f(a)=\pi(a)$.